# label control is not displayed on winform c#

Tags: c#

I have this code where I have to fetch 5 records in array from database. I have to display each record on each label. So I have generated runtime labels, used split function to split the array and then display each one of them on each label. When I run this code and click the button only one value is displayed. What is wrong with this code?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            addlabel(i);

        }

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < 5; i1++)
    {
        addlabel1(i1);
    }
}

void addlabel(int i)
{
    string cons = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cons);
    con.Open();
    string str = "SELECT * FROM marks  WHERE idno = " + textBox1.Text + "";

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var input = reader["subjects"].ToString();
        var split = input.Split(new string[] { ",", " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
        for (int j = 0; j < split.Length; j++)
        {
            Label l = new Label();
            l.Name = "label" + i.ToString();
            l.Text = split[j];
            l.Location = new Point(232, 100);
            this.Controls.Add(l);
        }

    }

}

void addlabel1(int i1)
{
    string cons = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cons);
    con.Open();
    string str = "SELECT * FROM marks  WHERE idno = " + textBox1.Text + "";

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {

        var input1 = reader["smarks"].ToString();
        var split1 = input1.Split(new string[] { ",", " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        for (int z = 0; z < split1.Length; z++)
        {
            Label l1 = new Label();
            l1.Name = "label" + i1.ToString();
            l1.Text = split1[z];
            l1.Location = new Point(353, 100);
            this.Controls.Add(l1);

        }
    }

}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You cant call all your labels the same thing "l1.Name = "label" + i1.ToString();"

Comment: @Lucifer Does it matter, aren't multiple accounts allowed? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts

Comment: @Freggar I didn't knew that

Comment: BTW, all the labels you are creating are in the same location, so they are one on top of the other, and you only can see the last one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You, probably, want something like this (printing out the values as a table):

```
 int left = 232;
 int top = 100;
 int step_x = 80;
 int step_y = 20;

 // outer loop - lines
 while (reader.Read()) {
   var split = Convert.ToString(reader["subjects"])
     .Split(new string[] { ",", " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 

   // inner loop - columns
   for (int j = 0; j < split.Length; j++) {
     new Label() {
       Name = $"label{i}",
       Text = split[j],
       // Notice "top + step_y * j" - label after label
       Location = new Point(left, top + step_y * j), 
       Parent = this, // equal to this.Controls.Add(l); 
     };
   }

   left += step_x;
 }
```

Comment: Please, check your query: `WHERE idno = " + textBox1.Text + ""` means that you filter out *one record* only.

Comment: Yes... on dat one id there is column name-"subjects" where total 5 subjects are stored.... I am fetching that as an array and want to display each subject on each label by spliting that array.... but the output is displaying only one subject on each label

Comment: Sorry, it seems to be a typo : `Location = new Point(left, top + step_y * j)` - `* j`, not `* i`